# set all even saturdays of every month to zero

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date

I have a dataframe with date column and a holiday column

I have been trying to set even saturdays to 0. For example if a month has 5 saturdays - 2nd and 4th saturday must be set to 0 and other saturdays must be 1.

**Code I tried:**

```
import pandas as pd

start_date = '2022-01-01'
end_date = '2022-12-31'

dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df['holiday'] = 1 
def is_weekend(d):
  if d.weekday() == 6:
    return 0
  elif d.weekday() == 5 and (d.day-1)//7%2 == 1:
    return 0
  else:
    return 1

df['holiday'] = df.apply(lambda row: is_weekend(row['date']) if row['holiday'] == 1 else 0, axis=1)
```

so here, all sundays are set to 0 since its a holiday and i tried setting every even saturday to 0. But For example, 30.07.2022 must be 1 (5th saturday) but its being set to 0 with my code.

How can I get only even saturdays as 0?

Comment: Can you give a meaningful reproducible example of data?

Comment: what is the type of `row['date']`?

Comment: @Vulwsztyn its is of type datetime64[ns] - YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: i updated with dummy data @mozway

Answer (score 1):

***you can use these codes***

```
start_date = '2022-01-01'
end_date = '2022-12-31'

dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.reset_index()
df["day"] = df["date"].dt.day_name()
df["holiday"] = df.apply(lambda x: 0 if any([x["day"]=="Sunday",(x["index"]%2==1 and x["day"]=="Saturday")]) else 1, axis=1)
df = df.drop(["index","day"], axis=1)
df
```